# SlickGrid Ajax call empty rows

Tags: json, jquery, slickgrid

I have a SlickGrid with AJAX call. I tracked it under Chrome and found out the data is correct but somehow grid shows all empty rows. Any idea why?

### Web service

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string LoadUsers()
    {
        List<Person> users = new List<Person>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = UtWeb.ConnectionGet())
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UserGet", conn);

            using (SqlDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    Person person = new Person();
                    person.LoginName = r["LoginName"].ToString();
                    person.FirstName = r["FirstName"].ToString();
                    person.LastName = r["LastName"].ToString();
                    users.Add(person);
                }
            }
        }

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person[]));
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, users.ToArray());
        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();            
    }
```

### Code

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.event.drag.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>
<script>

    var grid;
    var loader;
    var columns = [
    { id: "login-name", name: "Login Name", field: "LoginName" },
    { id: "firstname", name: "First Name", field: "FirstName" },
    { id: "lastname", name: "Last Name", field: "LastName" }
  ];

    var options = {
        editable: false,
        enableAddRow: false,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        enableColumnReorder: false
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'TestSlickGrid.aspx/LoadUsers',
            async: false,
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("ajax fail!");
            }
        });
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            if (parseInt(response) == 0)
                alert(response.d);
            else {
                loader = response; 
                grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", loader.d, columns, options);
            }

        }
    });    
</script>
```

In Chrome, it shows that 
loader.d = 
"[{"FirstName":"b","LastName":"bb","LoginName":"b"},{"FirstName":"","LastName":"","LoginName":"test1"},{"FirstName":"","LastName":"","LoginName":"test2"}]"

```
        loader = '{"employees":' + response.d + '}'; 
        var obj = eval("(" + loader + ")");
        grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", obj.employees, columns, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `loader.d` parsed as JSON, what does `alert(loader.d[0].LoginName)` show?

Comment: yes, this has some problems. please see the last section of code for update. that solution works but can it be cleaner?

Comment: `grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", JSON.parse(response.d), columns, options);` or `JSON.parse(loader)`. On older browsers you will need the JSON2.js library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give some height to your div in which your grid will be embedded. In your case I believe your div name is `myGrid`.

Try defining some height to this div and it will work. I have faced this issue and was able to fix by defining height to my div only.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. I also had similar issue and you have to have height defined, else slick grid shows blank rows. Other thing you have to check is what James has in his answer, that is matching data structure that you have (from api) and that you are binding.